# How to capitalise word in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a string like **web_shop_settings** and want it as ***Web Shop Settings***.
How to achieve it in C#.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Well, you'd write the code to do it, basically... iterate over the original string, applying conditions to decide when to capitalize the character in the result and when to remove the character entirely. How far have you got so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using *Linq*:

```
  string source = @"web_shop_settings";

  string result = string.Concat(source.Select((c, i) => c == '_'
    ? ' '
    : i == 0 || Char.IsWhiteSpace(source[i - 1]) || source[i - 1] == '_' 
       ? Char.ToUpper(c) 
       : c));
```

Comment: This does not replace the `_` with a space... and it will fail with non-ASCII chars ;)

Comment: @Lucero: I see, thank you! Your regex solution does work, so let my be Linq one.

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?:_|^)(\p{L})", (match) => (match.Index > 0 ? " " : "")+match.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper())
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer with regex so I thought I would add something done manually for reference:

```
        public string Transform(string input)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            string separator = null;

            foreach (var word in input.Split('_').Where(w => w.Length > 0))
            {
                if (separator == null)
                    separator = " ";
                else
                    stringBuilder.Append(separator);

                var firstLetter = word.Substring(0, 1);
                stringBuilder.Append(firstLetter.ToUpper());
                stringBuilder.Append(word.Substring(1));
            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Capitalize(this string source, char separator)
    {
        return 
            string.Join(" ", source.Split(new char[] { separator }).Select(
                c =>
                string.Format("{0}{1}", c[0].ToString().ToUpper(), c.Length > 1 ? c.Substring(1) : "")));
    }
}
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testString = "web_shop_settings";
        Console.WriteLine(testString.Capitalize('_'));
    }
}
```